# how to make a sliding door effect?

Tags: jquery

I want to have a sliding door effect, where the user clicks a link and a door comes down over the current content and goes up revealing the new content. Chris Carey did this in prototype, but I want to use jquery. Are there any plugins or tutorials? I saw one, but it was very basic.

[prototype example](http://www.chriscarey.info/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a basic example to get you started:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/yuF8S/3/ *(updated to switch content)*

js

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#door').animate({top:0}, 500, function() {
        $('#content > .contentItem').hide()
            .eq(index).show();
        $(this).animate({top: -200}, 500);
    });
});
```

html

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        <div class='contentItem'>content display 1</div>
        <div class='contentItem'>content display 2</div>
        <div class='contentItem'>content display 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id='door'></div>
</div>

<div id='links'>
    <a href='#'>content 1</a>
    <a href='#'>content 2</a>
    <a href='#'>content 3</a>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    clip: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.contentItem {
    display:none;
}
.contentItem:first-child {
    display:block;
}
#door {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    background: black;
}
#links {
    float: left;
} 
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: WOW where did you find? I was looking for something like that

Comment: @NEW: I just made it. It's really very simple.

Comment: The only thing this is missing is the switching of the old and new content when the "door" is completely "closed".

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#elementId").click(function(){
   $(this).slideUp();
});
```

slideDown() is the reciprocal.

Comment: Obligatory [documentation reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) link.

Comment: `slideUp()` will hide the element making `display: none`, the effect show on the website is a moving div, not a disappearing one.

Comment: Yes. hence slide being in the name. The point is that once the animation is finished the div needs to stay visible and maintain the same height throughout, another reason why `slideUp()` is inappropriate.

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow, sorry to make you look like you're talking to yourself. I posted my comment, realized what you meant, and deleted it before I saw that you had written a response.

Answer (score 1):

The basically want to move an absolutely positioned div when clicked upon to a new location using the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$('#moving-div').click(function() {
    if ($(this).position().top < 150) {
        $(this).animate({
            top: 200px
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            top: 100px
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: would this be the div or what would this be? sorry i am really new at this

Comment: No problem, my code is quite general. jQuery first selects the div which you wish to move (on the first line of code) then binds a function to be executed when a click even occurs on than div. When it does the function code decides whether to animate `this` (which is the moving div which the click event is bound to down or up. You will have to decide these boundaries yourself of course.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening there, is that he has three separate DIVs making up the three menus, only one is visible at a time.  Overlaying all of those menu DIVs, is a "door" as he has called it, a cover, it is at a higher *z-index* than the menu DIVs, so appears on top of it, if you setup your positioning properly.  The cover can be stretched in height resulting in the "door" growing over the top of the menu.

The process is:

1. let the click event on the button trigger the animation
2. animate() the height increase in the cover from its default size, to completely covering the menu
3. hide() the currently visible menu, and show() the one to be made visible
4. animate() the decrease in height of the cover to the default size

If you have the following HTML (making the first menu visible initially, the others hidden, and the cover at an "open" height just above the visible menu, with a higher z-index overlaying the visible menu):

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <div id="menu-contact" class="menu"></div>
    <div id="menu-home" class="menu"></div>
    <div id="menu-products" class="menu"></div>
</div>


<div id="buttons">
    <div id="contact" class="menu-button"></div>
    <div id="home" class="menu-button"></div>
    <div id="products" class="menu-button"></div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery can be:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
    var cMenuButton = $(this);
    var cMenuID = cMenuButton.attr('id');

    var coverHeight = $('#cover').height();
    var cVisibleMenu = $('.menu:visible');
    var cVisibleHeight = cVisibleMenu.height();

    $('#cover').animate({'height': coverHeight + cVisibleHeight}, 600, 'linear', function() {
        $('.menu').hide();
        $('#menu-' + cMenuID).show();

        var newMenuHeight = $('#menu-' + cMenuID).height();
        var coverHeight = $('#cover').height();

        $('#cover').animate({'height': coverHeight - newMenuHeight}, 600, 'linear');
    }); 
});
```

The **600** is the speed of the transition in milliseconds, that can be changed to suit.  This is slightly more complicated than the example you gave as I decided that it would be useful to show how to deal with a variable height menu.  If the menus are fixed height, you could do away with the calculations for the height and just use the open and closed heights.

Answer (score 1):

patrcik dw made an excellent example for starting, any way you said:

> goes up revealing the **new content**

So here is just an idea to get you going with this:

javascript:

```
$('p').hide();
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#door').animate({top:0}, 500, function() {
        $(this).animate({top: -200}, 500);
        $('p').show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href='#'>click me</a>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>some content to display</p>
    </div>
    <div id='door'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    clip: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#door {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    background: black;
}
```

It is exactly the same as patrcik´s code with the hide() and show() functions.

Good luck!

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yuF8S/2/)