# JQUERY Sliding door effect - works in jsFiddle but not chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do a sliding door effect using jquery. I have mocked it up in jsFiddle and it works okay in there. The problem I have, is when I run it locally, nothing works. I have downloaded and linked to the jquery library locally, and I have another project where I even link to the API and it works just fine. I don't understand what's going on here, as far as I can tell everything is loading okay, but when I click the link nothing happens.

here is the link the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/aosto/kU9HY/

edit: Also found that my code doesn't seem to work. I'm following [how to make a sliding door effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207789/how-to-make-a-sliding-door-effect), the direction provided by orbling. But I think I may have the CSS screwed up. Not sure how to initially hide the others and make one visible. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DBKustoms</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="./js/include.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="menu-container">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <div id="menu-home" class="menu"></div>
    <div id="menu-contact" class="menu">contact</div>
    <div id="menu-services" class="menu"></div>
    <div id="menu-photo" class="menu"></div>
</div>


<div id="buttons">
    <div id="home" class="menu-button">Home</div>
    <div id="contact" class="menu-button">Contact</div>
    <div id="services" class="menu-button">Services</div>
    <div id="photo" class="menu-button">Photo</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the CSS

```
#menu-container {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    clip: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }

#cover    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    background: black;
    z-index:1000;    
    }

#menu-home {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:blue;
    }

#menu-services {
    Height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:purple;

    }

#menu-contact {
    Height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    }

#menu-photo {
    Height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:brown;

}

#buttons {
    float:left;
}
```

and the JS

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
    var cMenuButton = $(this);
    var cMenuID = cMenuButton.attr('id');

    var coverHeight = $('#cover').height();
    var cVisibleMenu = $('.menu:visible');
    var cVisibleHeight = cVisibleMenu.height();

    $('#cover').animate({'height': coverHeight + cVisibleHeight}, 600, 'linear', function() {
        $('.menu').hide();
        $('#menu-' + cMenuID).show();

        var newMenuHeight = $('#menu-' + cMenuID).height();
        var coverHeight = $('#cover').height();

        $('#cover').animate({'height': coverHeight - newMenuHeight}, 600, 'linear');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the jquery stuff so it loads after DOM ready...

```
$(function(){
    // your js here
})
```

JSFiddle is doing that for you. The problem you encounter locally, is that the javascript runs before the document has loaded, so when the selector is selecting, there is nothing to select. If you run after DOM is ready, then it can select the HTML elements on the page as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put your code in a `document.ready`. On your jsfiddle there's a dropdown on your left that has the option onDomReady which wraps the code for you. Locally you don't, hence it works on jsfiddle.

```
$(function(){

  // code here
})
```

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, i'm fairly new to all this.

Comment: Please mark as answered if this helped solve your problem. Thanks!